# Delete unused Empty

Tags: python, objects, mirror

in my scene I had an object with a mirror-modifier attached. I made several copies of it. Now I discovered that it also copied the empty I used as the mirror object. I want all new objects using the same empty as mirror object. So I changed (most of) them to point to the original emtpy. Now I want to delete the unused copies of the empty. Is there a way to figure out which empties I can delete and which I have to keep because some are still used for mirroring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to delete all empties in the current scene, which are not used as mirror object by a mirror modifier, you can use the following script:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obs = set()

for ob in scene.objects:
    for mod in ob.modifiers:
        if mod.type == 'MIRROR':
            obs.add(mod.mirror_object)
            
for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'EMPTY' and ob not in obs:
        #scene.objects.unlink(ob) # version < 2.8 
        bpy.data.objects.remove(ob) # do unlink is default
```

Note that it will remove empties even if they are used by other modifiers for instance. There is no direct way to figure out all dependencies to tell what users a certain object has.

Answer (score -1):

This method works for me:

- Export as .fbx, unselect "empty" from object types
- Import .fbx in to a new Blender project

et, voila

Comment: Exporting and importing is rarely a correct solution for anything. Gone are any materials, modifiers, and properties your objects had