# How can I delete all 'unused empties' in a blend file?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, workflow, data-blocks

I have a huge blender file that contains many *empty objects*, and as a result it is very slow to work with that file.

Is there any way to have a python script that deletes objects of type `EMPTY`, but **only if the empty is not the parent of any other object?** I found a similar script [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21489/delete-unused-empty), but it works with a different  selection criteria.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**List comprehension**

Every now and then issues occur when removing objects from the collection that is being iterated over. (possibly an issue of the past) Now as a matter of choice I use list comprehension to create the filtered list.

For our filter, an empty has `None` for its data, and `[]` for `children` if none, both of which are boolean false.

**Note** [since the advent of empties as bg images, a more robust test for all empties is `e.type == 'EMPTY'`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227365/15543) and `do_unlink=True` has become the default option.

```
import bpy

childless_empties = [e for e in bpy.data.objects
        if e.type.startswith('EMPTY') and not e.children]

bpy.data.batch_remove(childless_empties)
```

Comment: This script worked for me in 2.8

Answer (score 3):

That should work :

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'EMPTY' and len(ob.children) == 0:
        scene.objects.unlink(ob)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
```

Comment: that worked like a charm, thanks very much!

Comment: Doesn't work in 3.5... first, the second to last line needs to be scene.collection.objects.unlink but that still leaves an error on the last line that the object which the script tries to remove is "not in collection 'Scene Collection'.

Comment: @eobet check the other answer. Iterating over a list while you remove elements from it is a big no no

Answer (score 0):

Is it permissible to link a better answer off-site, since none of the above work in Blender 3.5?

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-write-a-script-to-delete-all-unused-empties-from-a-collection/1387684/9

`bpy.data.batch_remove([o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.type == "EMPTY" and not o.children and not o.instance_collection])`

Comment: Hello. Nope, link-only answers are not considered good answers because they may rot in the future and it requires users to go on another website which is not a good experience. If you're worried about copyright and as I was pleasantly surprised to see you link a post of mine, I hereby grant you the right to share this piece of code. I'll edit your answer so it's available to everyone. But it's basically a one-liner that's doing exactly the same thing as batFINGER's

Comment: @Gorgious thank you! I noticed that even instanced collections get removed using this line, however, but I haven't had time to look into how to avoid that yet.

Comment: I've updated the answer to not remove instance collections