# Check whether an object is a reference image

Tags: python

In python, how to check whether an object is a reference image?

[image]

This line work only for checking empty-type :-

```
if obj.data is None :
```

Unfortunately, it is false for reference image.
I need to this condition to filter out invalid objects for `join()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use empty_display_type :

```
>>> print(bpy.data.objects["Empty"].empty_display_type)
IMAGE
```

So your test would look like :

```
if obj.empty_display_type == "IMAGE":
```

Answer (score 6):

**Look at the object type.**

[@thibsert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227363/15543) has answered the question at hand, Given

> I need to this condition to filter out invalid objects for `join()`.

*feel* this is somewhat of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

If you are joining objects, suggest looking at the `Object.type` property, since can only join objects of the same type.  For example sake let's assume you are joining mesh objects.

All selected mesh objects

```
mesh_obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
```

*ie* only interested in meshes, or to filter out non meshes

```
if ob.type != 'MESH':
    # continue
```

Similarly all empties in scene, regardless of empty display type

```
empties = [o of o in context.scene.objects if o.type == 'EMPTY']
```

*ie* as demonstrated `ob.data is None` is not a sufficient test for empties since the advent of reference images.  Testing for `obj.empty_display_type` without knowing the object is an empty will throw an error.  Hence a robust test for ref image object is

```
obj.type == 'EMPTY' and obj.empty_display_type == 'IMAGE'
```

Comment: Good to know. Nice, thanks.  ^^