# Selecting only single user objects

Tags: python

Is there a way via script to select only the single user objects in Blender 2.93?

I have tried to look into the bpy.ops.object.select_linked but this requieres having an object selected/active plus the fact I need to select the single users and not the linked ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Select all objects in scene where users is exactly 1.**

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    ob.select_set(ob.users == 1)
```

Similarly can look for objects that are single users of their data. An empty has `None` for data,  Will assume each empty ([not reference image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227361/check-whether-an-object-is-a-reference-image/227365#227365)) is a single user.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    ob.select_set(not ob.data or ob.data.users == 1)
```

Can also look at [`context.objects_in_mode_unique_data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.objects_in_mode_unique_data) which i find of most use in edit mode.