# Apply scale with multi-user objects blocking

Tags: transforms

I have many objects contained in my selection, both single-user and multi-user. I want to apply scale to all single-users, but Blender will throw an error, because it can't apply scale to multi-users. This is obvious, but in this case, Blender should sort them, ignore multi-user objects and let me apply scale to all single-users. But that doesn't happen.

I also don't want to break object links by making my multi-users into single-users.

I believe the real fix can only be done in Blender core development, so I will forward a feature request where possible (or maybe even a bug report).

For now, we could at least have a way to select only single-user or only multi-user objects. But I also couldn't find any tool for that.

Perhaps someone could help out with a script? It would be even more universal to script an object selector based on number of users.

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/227903/86891

Comment: Wow, yeah, it does. Thank You!

Comment: I didn't find that thread, even though I was typing almost exactly its title. I believe Blender should still ignore multi-users by default, but for now it'll do the job.

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that the devs are planning to improve it, yes, but no idea when or how it will be done :)